# Need a simple and easy pagination in html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

Need easy and light paging in HTML table using jquery.
I have use webservice to fill the table with the help of JSON.
Now I need to add paging. Thanks in advance. Structure of my HTML table

```
<tr>
    <th> Id </th>
    <th> Code </th>
    <th> Name </th>
    <th> Gender </th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look here, its simple to use

```
http://neoalchemy.org/tablePagination.html
```

One more tool base on the work of first one

```
https://code.google.com/p/one-simple-table-paging/
```

Comment: I am frequently getting "Jquery undefined" whenever i try to implement paginate

Comment: have you included all the jquery files necessary

Comment: yea did it, it would be helpful if u share me a sample

Comment: @user3256201 have you checked the Network through Inspect Element ? Is there any Error ?

Answer (score -1):

You could search the list of jQuery plugins: http://plugins.jquery.com/?s=pagination

Comment: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'oneSimpleTablePagination'

Comment: The plugins are build on the jQuery framework. You must include jQuery as a `script` reference in your document before attempting to make use of the plugins or other jQuery code. Google has a CDN here: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide
You can link to one of their hosted jquery libraries, or download it, and link to it locally within your website.

Comment: receiving the same one again and again